# Using ! in a function call in C

Tags: c, function

Can someone help me with an explanation of how to understand the ! operator in function calls in C?
For example, `bool misspelled = !check(word);`
The check() function in this case is supposed to return a bool. So does the ! here mean that misspelled will be assigned the opposite value of whatever check() returns?

I haven't tried using it yet. I'm still a beginner, learning the meaning and usage of C.

Comment: It works exactly as you suspected.

Comment: The bang operator, `!` flips the boolean value from true to false or false to true.  Or just as you suggested, the opposite value of the expression.

Comment: The `!` operator is just a unary operator.  `!x` is equivalent to `x == 0`.  In your case, the function is called, then the result is logically negated:  If it's equal to `0`, the result is `1`, otherwise the result is `0`.

Comment: This `if(x)` is the same as `if(x == true)`. This `if(!x)` is the same as `if(x == false)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane That is only true when `x` is a canonical boolean.  If it's `7`, or `3.5`, then the first example does not hold.

Comment: @TomKarzes OP stated that the function returns a `bool`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, in that context it's true, but taken out of context it's very misleading.  The best way to define `!x` is as `x == 0`.

Comment: @TomKarzes both examples hold when `x == 7`. One doesn't use the `!` operator with floating point.

Comment: @WeatherVane No.  If `x` is `7`, then it's not a `bool` and will compare unequal to `true`.  Try it:  `7 == true` is `0`.  And if `x` is ` bool`, and you assign `7` to it, then it will not compare equal to `7`.

Comment: @TomKarzes any non-0 integer value is true. Aside: I hate `bool` and never found a need to use it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, of course I realize that.  What you said was factually wrong:  You claimed that `7 == true` evaluated to true.  It doesn't.  `if (7)` and `if (7 == true)` are not equivalent.  You said they were.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255418/discussion-between-weather-vane-and-tom-karzes).

Comment: For what it's worth, here's how the C standard defines the `!` operator:  The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

Comment: This is the operator for `NOT`. It is the same case as `~` for bitwise not or `^`  for `XOR`: hard to read inside an expression. But *NOT* is far more common, and some languages admits using plain and simple  **not** for the same effect. In C it is possible if you`#include iso646.h` and it can make a difference. Many people will dislike it, after seeing a `not` they would not seen if it was an  `!`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There is nothing special about "`!` in a function call" - the `!` and the function call are not related. The function call is just the `check(word)` part, which evaluates to either `true` or `false`, and then the `!` is applied on that, so it's as if either `!true` or `!false` were written there.

You could as well write `bool x = fn(); bool y = !x;` as you can write `bool y = !fn();`.

It's the same as how you could do `int x = fn(); int y = fn2(); int z = (x + 5) * y;` as well as you could write `int z = (fn() + 5) * fn2());`.

It's as in Math - if I write `-sin(x)` that `-` also isn't special or different from any other `-` as in `-1` or `-x` and it's not part of the application of the sine function in any way, it's just applied on its result.

Answer (score 2):

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is:
> 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0,
> 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0.
> The result has type `int`.
> The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.
> [C23dr](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) § 6.5.3.3 5